# How to identify the string and change it with default value

Tags: ios, string, swift3

Hi I have a string link Example: "user: jon,nick,roy"
I want to identify user name "nick" in the string and I want to replace the user name "nick" to "you". can anyone help me with it. Thanks :)

Example: "jon,nick,roy" to "jon,you,roy"

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
"jon,nick,roy".replacingOccurrences(of: "nick", with: "you")
```